# How to implement RoutingDSL in Java Play Framework 2.4

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I just starting to learn Play framework 2.4 using Java, and I confused for using RoutingDSL in my application.

I already read documentation about that on here (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaRoutingDsl) and here (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/routing/RoutingDsl.html), but I don't know how to implement that on my application.

Do I need to put that on Global Settings or Controller? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: What makes you implement your own routing? Can't you use `routes` file?

Comment: I think it's not the best way to manage routing for big web application. @MonCalamari

Comment: Have you actually tried it? In my opinion, having all the routes in one file is really handy. It greatly improves webdev productivity. Btw, I work with app which has over 700 routes in `routes` file.